# NWPathMonitor Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0)

Tags: ios, swift, flutter, xcode

I am facing an **issue** when I try to run the app on my real iOS device. Please help me solve my problem. I've tried many ways to fix it, such as changing the **Minimum Deployment Target** from **11.0** to **12.0**.

---

### Things that need to be considered

I researched this error and found it might be caused by the **package_info_plus** package. However, I'm not certain. I've tried upgrading both Flutter and **package_info_plus** to their **latest versions**, but the issue persists.

### The Error

[image]

### Flutter Doctor

[image]

### Error occurred while running the app in Xcode

[image]

Comment: You can see the the crash is in connectivity_plus; this seems to be the relevant issue https://github.com/fluttercommunity/plus_plugins/issues/1955; do you have version 5.0.1 of that plug-in?

Comment: Yes, I use version 5.0.1.

Comment: That issue matches your problem exactly and seems to be a confirmed fix when building against the iOS 17 SDK.  Do a build->clean in Xcode.

Comment: Not working bro.

Have you ever tried downgrading the macOS version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Upgrade both **flutter** and **connectivity_plus** to the **latest version**
2. In **Xcode**, change the **minimum deployment target** from 11.0 to 12.0 or higher.

[image]

3. Edit the **Podfile** located within the **ios** directory of your Flutter project.

From This

[image]

To This

[image]

4. Go to **Xcode** > **Product** > **Clean Build Folder**.

[image]

5. Rebuild your project

Comment: The reason your changes in Xcode were ignored is because of having the part that you show in step 3. Your projects shouldn't override deployment targets this way as it is a potential cause of issues, like the one you had.

Comment: Here is also an explanation from one of Flutter team members about why you shouldn't override deployment target this way: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/94491#issuecomment-1703029131